# Access Denied on Modifying the Amazon RDS PostgreSQL DB Version

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to upgrade the RDS PostgreSQL DB Version from 9.4.18 (PostgreSQL 9.4.18-R1) to 9.5.13 (PostgreSQL 9.5.13-R1) where AWS RDS console automatically changes the DB parameter group from default.postgres9.4 to default.postgres9.5. But when I click on the Modify DB Instance button I get below error, looking at error message it says access denied while modifying the parameter group but wait I'm not trying to modify the default parameter group which is created by AWS automatically. Not sure what I'm missing here?

```
User 99999999 is not authorized to modify 
database instance arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:pg:default.postgres9.5 (Service: AmazonRDS; 
Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; 
Request ID: 26f09b9b-b205-42d5-8bf4-56a9560ab223). 
Please check with your administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I was missing some permissions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:ModifyDBInstance"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:db:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:pg:default*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:ModifyDBParameterGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:pg:default*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```